# How to render a view based on the logged in user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firebase-authentication

I am trying to do the following: in the frontend I get the user email and then send it to the server with a fetch. I want to render different pages, either a default one or the admin page if the user logged in uses the admin email.

However, when I start the server, it automatically renders the default page since it doesn't see the user logged in unless I refresh the page (but even after the page refresh the default page is the one rendered)

EDIT: It renders correctly after 1-2 page refreshes.. 
Here is my frontend code:

```
$(function () {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    var email = undefined;
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
      email = user.email;
    } else {
      // No user is signed in.
    }
    fetch('/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email
      })
    });
  });

// other methods
});
```

Here is my approach in the backend:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('dotenv').config();
}

const gmailAcc = process.env.gmailAcc
const gmailPass = process.env.gmailPass

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs'); 

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static('public/'));

app.all('/', function async (req, res) {
     fs.readFile('items.json', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).end();
        } else {
            email = req.body.email;
            console.log('email in backend', email, email == gmailAcc);
            if (email == gmailAcc) { //admin
                console.log('admin');
                res.render('admin.ejs', {
                    items: JSON.parse(data)
                });
            } else {
                console.log('not admin');
                res.render('index.ejs', {
                    items: JSON.parse(data)
                });
            }
        }
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar issue. I tried reloading the page with window.reload() in the firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged() method, however it does NOT work because the page refreshes infinitely.